# javascript let not working in various browsers

Tags: javascript, let

`let` doesnt't work in some browsers.  Not in their interpeters/ web consoles either.  Why?

(originally I thought there was an inconsistency b/t the browser interpeter and the jsFiddle, but it turns out not to be true, just bad tests on my part.)

Comment: If your bowser doesn't support it, it won't work in JSFiddle either. Can you a link a fiddle where it does "work"?

Comment: @EliranMalka: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#let_statement

Comment: @Alex Wayne:  Not sure why I'd thought I'd tested it.

Comment: seriously when will they stop adding useless features to javascript

Comment: @mihai: what makes you say it's useless?

Comment: @user420667 the example uses don't justify its existence.

Comment: @Mathletics: How 'bout these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet , specifically the for heads part?

Comment: @user420667 YMMV, but that is not a real problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a non-standard keyword introduced in JS 1.7, not necessarily implemented in different browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Only implemented in Gecko, from what I understand. What Mozilla calls 'Javascript 1.7' has nothing to do with 'Ecmascript' which is what everybody implements.

Answer (score 5):

In order to use some of the new features of JavaScript 1.7, you need to [specify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Block%5Fscope%5Fwith%5Flet) that you wish to use JavaScript 1.7. In HTML or XUL code, use

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"/>
```