# How to use let (or other JS 1.7 features) in the web console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools, javascript-1.7

I was wanting to test some things with `let` statement *in the console*, but I ran into a problem - it isn't supported in Firefox or Chromium. I know it's supported, if you [set the javascript version in a script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388519), but is there any option that will let you make sure the latest version of Javascript is enabled in the web console (or Scratchpad) of Firefox and/or Chromium?

Comment: Firefox already supports it in the Web console. For Chromium, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17253177/938089.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me in the Firefox console.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to bring up the console and:

[image: let x = 3; undefined x 3]

Comment: Interesting. I tried `let x=3 { console.log(x); }` and it doesn't work.

Comment: @NoBugs you need to wrap the x=3 in parens: "let (x=3){console.log(x)}"

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no such thing as a window.version or something like that... the common way is by checking like posted in [Detect version of JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340726/detect-version-of-javascript)

or even better heck out [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), which is a great library that does feature detection for you.

Comment: Thank, but I know it supports JS1.7, the question is, how to use it without making a new script tag in a document, with the `type="application/javascript;version=1.7"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you have to activate JavaScript Harmony,"chrome://flags"
 [image: enable-javascript-harmony]

and use the strict mode `"use strict";`.

Here's a simple example:

```
"use strict";
let square = "trololo";
console.log(square);
```